# UNIXTIMEFORMAT formula issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to covert a timestamp value in my data to **'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'** using UNIXTIMEFORMAT formula but it is giving a wrong result as you can see in the screenshot here.

Unixtime 1592574691 translates to ==> 2020-06-19 17:51:31 but dataprep is converting to 1970-22-19 10:22:54

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your `click_time` is in seconds but UNIXTIMEFORMAT needs miliseconds. Try to multiply your column by 1000

```
UNIXTIMEFORMAT($col * 1000, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss')
```